# Django custom authentication class is not reading AllowAny

Tags: python, django

Here is the REST authentication class:

```
def get_authorization_header(request):
    raw_token = request.COOKIES.get('auth_token', ) or None
    auth = request.META.get('HTTP_AUTHORIZATION', )
    if isinstance(auth, str):
        auth = auth.encode(HTTP_HEADER_ENCODING)
    return auth


class JWTAuthentication(BaseAuthentication):
    keyword = 'auth_token'

    def authenticate(self, request):
        raw_token = request.COOKIES.get('auth_token', ) or None
        if raw_token is None:
            return None

        return self.authenticate_credentials(raw_token)

    def authenticate_credentials(self, key):
        try:
            user_model = get_user_model()
            payload = jwt.decode(key, settings.SECRET_KEY, algorithms="HS256")
            user = user_model.objects.get(email=payload['email'])
        except (jwt.DecodeError, user_model.DoesNotExist):
            raise exceptions.ParseError('Invalid token')
        except jwt.ExpiredSignatureError:
            raise exceptions.ParseError('Token has expired')
        if not user.is_active:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('User inactive or deleted')

        return (user, payload)

    def authenticate_header(self, request):
        return self.keyword
```

And here is the view:

```
class GoogleLogin(APIView):

    permission_classes = [AllowAny]
    def post(self, request):
        data = request.data
        response = Response()
        token = data.get('tokenId', None)

        if not token:
            raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed('No credentials provided.')

        try:

            token_info = id_token.verify_oauth2_token(token, requests.Request(), google_app_id)
            email = token_info['email']
            user = authenticate(email)

            if not user:
                serializer = RegisterSerializer(data={'email': token_info['email'], 'first_name': token_info['given_name'], 'last_name': token_info['family_name']})
                serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
                serializer.save()

            jwt_token = gen_token(email)

            response.set_cookie(
                key='auth_token',
                value=jwt_token,
                expires=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(days=30),
                secure=False,
                httponly=True,
                samesite='Lax'
            )

            return response
        except ValueError:
            return Response('Invalid TokenId.', status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

I'm trying to implement Google social login where the frontend (ReactJS) sends `tokenId` to the backend (Django) to verify the token then returns a response with a JWT token stored in the cookies (cookie name is `auth_token`) as shown by this line `response.set_cookie` now when I try to login while I don't have the authentication token (I don't have `auth_token` in my cookies) everything works fine but when I try to login while I have an expired authentication token I get `'Token has expired'` message even though I set the permission class to `AllowAny`

I think I implemented my authentication class wrong by I can't figure out where the issue is

Answer (score 2):

`AllowAny` comes after authentication for checking registered or anonymous user has permission. If auth fail, request is blocked before permissions.

On your code, if there is no token, anonymous user can access login view. Auth accepts  request.
There is no way for ExpiredToken to pass auth, because you raise exception.

Actually, your code does the right thing. If token is expired, front should delete invalid token, redirect to login page and make user push login button again without COOKIE.